# Точный таймер C# Timer (System.Windows.Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер, countdown, countdowntimer

Есть программа, которая в заданное время, по таймеру, копирует файлы. Значение времени копирования, указывается в DateTimePicker (отображает только время).

Значение времени из DateTimePicker записывается в переменную ScheduledTime, затем она сравнивается с DateTime.Now и если значение ScheduledTime меньше, то добавляется 1 день. Функция GetSetScheduledTime():

```
if (DateTime.Now > ScheduledTime)
   {
    while (DateTime.Now >= ScheduledTime)
      {
        ScheduledTime = ScheduledTime.AddDays(1);
        DateTimePickerTimer.Value = DateTimePickerTimer.Value.AddDays(1);
      }
   }
```

Цикл while используется для чтения даты из конфиг файла, где дата может быть старой.

После уточнения ScheduledTime получаем интервал TickTime  для таймера:

```
  TickTime = (int)(GetSetScheduledTime() - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

            if (TickTime >= 0)
            {
                TimerPl.Interval = TickTime;
                //Start Main Timer
                TimerPl.Start();
            }
```

После того, как таймер срабатывает, в функции TimerTick таймер останавливается, запускается функция копирования, отсылаются отчеты и записывается лог и снова запускается функция таймера, проверяется время, получается новый интервал и снова ждем следующего срабатывания.

Проблема в том, что время плавает. В первый день, на 2 разных компьютерах, таймер сработал точно, на второй день, сработал раньше на 1 секунду и на 2 секунды. Будет ли возрастать это время пока не ясно.

Я понимаю что таймер не является точным инструментом и тики могут запаздывать или идти быстрее. Но если у нас есть значение из DateTimePicker, где время не меняется, а только увеличивается на 1 день и потом это значение присваивается ScheduledTime и если я каждый раз получаю новый интервал который равен - время планирования - текущее время, разве должна или может ошибка накапливаться? Как этого избежать? Я не против люфта до 5 секунд, но если это значение будет постоянно возрастать, как корректировать время?

UPD: Короче добиться точного времени не удалось, но поскольку задача так и не стояла, то имею люфт в секунду. Учитываю это при формировании следующей даты, обнуляю все значения где нужно и все работает. Таймеры шарпа не лучшее решение, там где нужно точное время. По возможности старайтесь их избегать.

Comment: С чего вы решили, что проблема в таймере? Вы меняете интервал таймера синхронно? Может, ваши операции, что вы делаете, на разных машинах занимают разное время, от того и рассинхрон.

Comment: @tym32167 Я думаю что проблема в Таймере потому, что если бы он срабатывал позже, то можно было бы списать все это на то что функция копирования дольше копирует на разных машинах. Но он срабатывает раньше. При чем на машине где постоянно помимо этого еще что то делается, он срабатывает на 1 секунду раньше, а на другой машине, которая просто стоит и ничего не делает - на 2 секунды раньше. В целом, программа работает (и будет работать) на 1 компьютере. Просто тестил ее на 2 и получил разный результат.

Comment: Вы меняете интервал таймера, а значит он может быть как больше, так и меньше. Я бы на вашем месте логгировал все подряд, включая выставленные интервалы и даты/время их выставления + подготовил бы минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Таймер, конечно, штука не особо точная, но 2 секунды расхождения за сутки и 2 запуска — это перебор

Comment: Используйте планировщик Windows для этих целей.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну пока я не вижу великого смысла в этом. По результатам вчера, погрешность составляет =- 1 секунда у таймера. Мне не принципиально важно что бы он запускался точно вовремя. Просто из-за плавающего времени, пока не было обработки и проверок, вываливалась ошибка. Сейчас поправил это. Но глобально, проблема с таймерами я вижу есть у всех. а адекватных решений, я нигде не нашел. Поэтому и спросил.

Comment: Если вам нужна повышенная точность, почему бы не выставить таймер на время за минуту до нужного, и оттуда отсчитывать по секундам (без таймера)?

Comment: @VladD Ну сейчас я таки решил вопрос с точностью. Люфт в пару секунд допустимый. Пока все работает хорошо. Проблема была в том, что без дополнительных проверок, когда таймер срабатывал раньше, получалось отрицательное значение для параметра интервал таймера. Теперь я ввел проверку на +- 5 секунд и сделал так, что если параметр отрицательный, то ждать некоторое время и снова получить дату планирования. Это решило проблему. В данном случае это была самая главная проблема. Точность не столько важна иначе можно было бы использовать StopWatch или другие варианты.

Comment: @DmStk: Тогда, возможно, напишете ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос с точностью таймера, для данной ситуации я решил так. У меня на форме, есть DateTimePicker, который при запуске программы (если в конфиге нет сохраненных данных), инициализируется DateTime.Today - т.е. сегодняшний день, 00:00:00. 
Есть функция:

```
    DateTime GetSetScheduledTime()
    {
        //Получаем время из DateTimePicker - дата меня не интересует
        ScheduledTime = DateTimePickerTimer.Value;
        //Первая проверка. Если текущее время больше ScheduledTime то добавлять день\дни
        if (DateTime.Now > ScheduledTime)
        {
            //Проверить Scheduled Date и добавить день или дни, если в конфиге старая дата 
            while (DateTime.Now >= ScheduledTime)
            {
                ScheduledTime = ScheduledTime.AddDays(1);
                DateTimePickerTimer.Value = DateTimePickerTimer.Value.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
        //Вторая проверка. Если текущее время +-5 секунд больше ScheduledTime
        if (DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5) > ScheduledTime || DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-5) > ScheduledTime)
        {
            ScheduledTime = ScheduledTime.AddDays(1);
            DateTimePickerTimer.Value = DateTimePickerTimer.Value.AddDays(1);
        }
        //Если таймер установлен на 00:00:00 то добавить 1 день.
        if (ScheduledTime == DateTime.Today)
        {
            ScheduledTime = ScheduledTime.AddDays(1);
            DateTimePickerTimer.Value = DateTimePickerTimer.Value.AddDays(1);
        }
        return ScheduledTime;
    }
```

В ней, как видно есть 3 проверки. Дальше, эта функция вызывается в Старте Таймера:

```
void TimerStart() {
        try {
            GetSetScheduledTime();
            //Milliseconds Value to Main Timer
            TickTime = (int)(GetSetScheduledTime() - 
            DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

            if (TickTime >= 0) {
                TimerPl.Interval = TickTime;
                //Start Main Timer
                TimerPl.Start();
            }
            else {
                //Wait 5 seconds
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                GetSetScheduledTime();
                TickTime = (int)(GetSetScheduledTime() - 
                DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

                if (TickTime >= 0){
                    TimerPl.Interval = TickTime;
                    TimerPl.Start();
                }
                else { //выбросить исключение }
            }
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) {
            TimerPl.Stop();
            //Отправляем логи и т.д.
        }
    }
```

При Тике таймера - останавливаю таймер, запускаю функцию копирования, в ней еще раз вызываю GetSetScheduledTime, отправляю почту и логи. Запускаю таймер и все идет по новой. Немного сократил код что бы не получилась простынь. В таком варианте, все работает. Таймер запускается на секунду раньше, но это уже не столько важно. Точное время мне не нужно. Мне нужно что бы оно копировало. А если будут проблемы, то идут отчеты на почту и есть достаточно времени что бы зайти удаленно и все сделать. Поскольку копируется с десяток текстовых файлов, то функция копирования пролетает очень быстро. Для других случаев такой вариант не факт что будет работать норм. 
Я понимаю что код примитивный, но это то что получилось написать после более чем 2 летнего перерыва.